# Why does subtracting the equations of two intersecting circles give the line that intersects the points of intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, circles

Why does subtracting the equations of two intersecting circles give the line that intersects the points of intersection?

In other words, why does the elimination method give a line that also intersects the point of intersection?

Comment: Because subtracting two equations $x^2+y^2+\cdots$ eliminates the quadratic terms.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with together with the context.  Stuffing the problem statement into the title and using the body only for brief clarification puts a burden on your Readers to bridge the gap, and this invites confusion.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks I shall note that for the future. Though I recall reading on the page that as much detail should be given in the title as possible.

Comment: We do want [a clear title](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).  This helps Readers to spot Questions that may be useful or interesting.  I think your title is fine here, but "as much detail... as possible" is not the advice I'd give for titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any point that satisfies both equations also satisfies any linear combination of the two equations. Put another way, the curve described by the combined equation also passes through the intersection points of the two circles. If you eliminate the quadratic terms by subtracting one circle equation from the other, you’re left with the equation of a straight line.

Proving the first statement is quite straightforward: the two equations can be put in the form $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$. If some point $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfies these equations, then $$\lambda f(x_0,y_0)+\mu g(x_0,y_0)=0\lambda+0\mu=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract, you get
(1) an equation of a line,
and
(2) any point on both circles satisfies both equations, and therefore their difference.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that last point?

Comment: If a point $(x,y)$ satisfies each of two equations, then $(x,y)$ also satisfies their difference.  I guess if you do not understand this, you need to go back and review your algebra?

Comment: Do you mean, any point on both circles [that] satisfies both equations, and therefore their difference. I get that that is true, but is there a way to prove that this is true apart from trying out different values? And thank you for the advice but it's not clear what level of algebra you are referring to i.e. GCSE, A level or University?